# How to play an AVI file in a video tag?

Tags: html, video, html5-video

I'm wondering if it's possible to make a browser play a AVI file within a `video` tag.

Everything I found on the web talking about it focus on MP4 and Ogg formats but nobody talks about the AVI format.

The only solution I found is to drop the `video` tag and make the video playable using JW Player.

Answer (score 10):

Only the DivX web player can stream avi files. actually, theres a plug in for vlc to stream avi files also, but its buggy.

Sometimes it's a pain in the ass to get a solid answer. its one of the big sucks of the internet.

```
<object id="ie_plugin" classid="clsid:67DABFBF-D0AB-41fa-9C46-CC0F21721616" 
            width="660" 
            height="300" 
            codebase="http://go.divx.com/plugin/DivXBrowserPlugin.cab"> 
<param name="custommode" value="stage6" />
<param name="autoPlay" value="false" />
<param name="src" value="link-to-avi" />
<param name="bannerEnabled" value="false" />

<embed id="np_plugin" type="video/divx" 
src="link-to-avi" 
custommode="stage6" 
width="660" 
height="300" 
autoPlay="false"  
bannerEnabled="false"
pluginspage="http://go.divx.com/plugin/download/">
</embed>
</object>
```

note where it says "link-to-avi" twice :)

Comment: [WebChimera](http://www.webchimera.org/) also streams avi files, it's based on libvlc.dll. It should be noted that avi files do not show the "Total Length Time" in WebChimera, and I don't believe it's shown in any plugin. This is not a bug, the problem is with avi encoding itself as total time can only be calculated from the entire file, so it can't be gotten from only partial files (like when streaming). I've also tried using ffprobe (from ffmpeg) to get the "Total Length Time" of avi files, and it always failed until the entire file was downloaded locally.

Comment: This is the only answer which I have found with respect to avi videos . Great answer .

Comment: This is the only answer that provides a working code. Too bad chrome blocks the plugin.

Comment: Doesn't work in Edge/Chrome, and WebChimera link isn't found.

Answer (score 0):

Today there are excellent approaches to deal with it. One of them is the module  [fluent-ffmpeg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fluent-ffmpeg) found on npm.

It requires the previous installation of [FFMPEG](https://www.ffmpeg.org/)

The support of avi isn't direct. It will be necessary build a server with node to serve your html.